# MYSQL Variable not found

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL database which have a 'project' varchar column within one of the tables. When i insert variables into this column via my php pages (eg; project = WT) when i do a select query where project = 'WT' nothing comes up. 
What makes it even stranger, if i edit the value via phpMyAdmin panel to the same value it is then able to be found in the select query.

Comment: Please show us your INSERT and SELECT statements...

Comment: Try `project LIKE '%WT%'` to see if you somehow have put leading or trailing spaces into your data. Or, try `SELECT project, LENGTH(project) FROM table` to find out the same thing. Look for surprising values of `LENGTH()`.

Comment: You are a genius! Nearly solved my problem. It says length is 3, but shows no leading or trailing spaces or additional characters.

Comment: LIKE '%WT' comes up with nothing still but LIKE 'WT%' comes up with all of my rows... So there is something at the end of the string that is invisible stopping it from working...

Comment: SELECT ASCII(substr(project,3,1)) will show you the ASCII value of the character in the 3rd position. It is possibly an invisible character. If you get a result, use the ASCII chart here to find out what it is: http://www.asciitable.com/. Of course you could simply run an update and replace project with substr(project,1,2)

Comment: I used regexp to remove everything oter than letters. Worked a treat. Thanks ollie jones.

Comment: Ugh, I'd rather sanitize your insert query and trim the string that you're inserting. The solution you chose gives you 'dirty' data in the database that you sanitize in the SELECT query, which is just, umm, simply wrong. :)